# UIDatePicker to set UITextfield text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a `UITextField` and a `UIDatePicker` which I want to use to set the Birthday of the user.

I use this code in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
birtdayTextField.inputView = datePicker;
```

However I have 2 problems. I've placed a `UIDatePicker` in my view in the storyboard. But it still opens a new `datepicker` even though I've connected the `*datepicker` to the `UIDatePicker`.

And also it doesn't add the info from the `datepicker` to the `textfield`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input view doesn't work so. You may create lazy `UIDatePicker`:

```
- (UIDatePicker *)bDatePicker {
    if (!_bDatePicker) {
        _bDatePicker = [UIDatePicker new];
        _bDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
        [_bDatePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerDidChangeDate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    }
    return _bDatePicker;
}
```

Then set it like following:

```
self.birtdayTextField.inputView = self.bDatePicker;
```

And this is the callback:

```
- (void)datePickerDidChangeDate:(UIDatePicker *)sender {
    self.birtdayTextField.text = [self.bDateFormatter stringFromDate:sender.date];
}
```

Possible formatter:

```
- (NSDateFormatter *)bDateFormatter {
    if (!_bDateFormatter) {
        _bDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
        _bDateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yyyy";
    }
    return _bDateFormatter;
}
```

To prevent pasting wrong data to that text field you may use it's `delegate`:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return textField != self.birtdayTextField;
}
```